# R package for zip code & other geodata from IP addresses?

Tags: r

I have a list of about 200,000 IP addresses. I would like to link these to geographic location and get any other data that an IP address can give as well.

The best I've found so far is a service provided by infochimps:
http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/digital-element-ip-intelligence-demographics
There's also an R package for infochimps. But infochimps requires you to pay and for 200,000 IP addresses this could get expensive.

Is there any R package that can do something like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [`RDSTK`](https://github.com/rtelmore/RDSTK) package, which provides an R interface to the Data Science Toolkit API. Here is a [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/rtelmore/drug-rdstk-talk) by the author of the package, that should help you get started.

***From Xu Wang's comments (moved here to increase future findability):***
For reference purposes: To install that package, one must install RCurl and rjson. Before installing RCurl, on Ubuntu I had to install two packages: `sudo apt-get install curl libcurl4-gnutls-dev` The function that I needed was `ip2coordinates`, which accepts an IP address as input

Comment: thank you, this seems to work great. For reference purposes:

To install that package, one must install `RCurl` and `rjson`. Before installing `RCurl`, on Ubuntu I had to install two packages:
`sudo apt-get install curl libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

The function that I needed was `ip2coordinates`, which accepts an IP address as input

Answer (score 2):

The function IPtoXY (http://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2011/12/function-to-collect-geographic.html) uses the same API but does not need additional packages..

**Edit, 26th of Sept**:
Thanks to @Peter M I became aware that my function mentioned above was not working anymore - here is the edited version which should work (also the link above was updated..):

```
# Purpose: Get geographic coordinates for a given IP-address
# Author: Kay Cichini
# Date: 2011-12-18
# Output: A string holding longitude and latitude with format "X;Y"

IPtoXY <- function(x) {
   URL_IP <- paste("http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org//ip2coordinates/",
                   x, sep = "")

   api_return <- readLines(URL_IP, warn = F)
   lon1 <- api_return[grep("longitude", api_return)]
   lon <- gsub("[^[:digit:].]", "", lon1)
   lat1 <- api_return[grep("latitude", api_return)]
   lat <- gsub("[^[:digit:].]", "", lat1)
   return(paste(lat, lon, sep = ";"))
}

# Example:
> IPtoXY("74.88.200.52")
[1] "40.951301574707;73.78759765625"
```

Answer (score 1):

The function from: http://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2011/12/function-to-collect-geographic.html , does not work.

But the idea still does, so this should do:

```
iplocation <- function(ip=""){
  response    <- readLines(paste("http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org//ip2coordinates/",ip,sep=""))
  success     <- !any(grepl("null",response))

  ip <- grep("[[:digit:]]*\\.[[:digit:]]*\\.[[:digit:]]*\\.[[:digit:]]*",response,value=T)
    match <- regexpr("[[:digit:]]*\\.[[:digit:]]*\\.[[:digit:]]*\\.[[:digit:]]*",ip)
    ip <- substr(ip,match,as.integer(attributes(match)[1])+match-1)
  if(success==T){
    extract <- function(label,response){
            text <- grep(label,response,value=T)
            match <- regexpr(paste('"',label,'"',": ",sep=""),text)
            text <- substr(text,match+as.integer(attributes(match)[1]),nchar(text))
            if(grepl("[[:digit:]]",text)){
                    text <- substr(text,1,nchar(text)-2)
            }else{
                    text <- substr(text,2,nchar(text)-2)
                }
            if( regexpr('"',text)!= -1){
                text<-substr(text,2,nchar(text))
            }
            print(text)
            text
        }
  }
  RESULT <- list()
  RESULT$success     <- success
  RESULT$ip          <- ip
  if(success==T){
    RESULT$latitude    <- as.numeric(extract("latitude",response))
    RESULT$longitude   <- as.numeric(extract("longitude",response))
    RESULT$country     <- extract("country_name",response)
    RESULT$locality    <- extract("locality",response)
    RESULT$postalcode  <- extract("postal_code",response)
    RESULT$region      <- extract("region",response)
    RESULT$countrycode <- extract("country_code3",response)
  }
  RESULT
}

iplocation()
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across [ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io) for looking up IP addresses. I just used RCurl library to handle these:

```
R> library(RCurl)
R> getURL("http://ipinfo.io/74.125.227.224")
[1] "{\n  \"ip\": \"74.125.227.224\",\n  \"hostname\": \"dfw06s38-in-f0.1e100.net\",\n  \"city\": \"Mountain View\",\n  \"region\": \"California\",\n  \"country\": \"US\",\n  \"loc\": \"37.4192,-122.0574\",\n  \"org\": \"AS15169 Google Inc.\",\n  \"postal\": \"94043\"\n}"
```

The requests can be modified if interested in just postal code for example:

```
R> getURL("http://ipinfo.io/74.125.227.224/postal")
[1] "94043\n"
```